# Checking if a directory is empty when having over a million files inside

Tags: performance, file-system, php5

I have the following function to confirm if a directory contains files:

```
/**
 * Check if the directory is empty
 * 
 * Function to ascertain if the specified directory contains files.
 * Comparing to two, because parent and current are present inside
 * the returned array. Only 3+ denotes files on the target dir.
 * 
 * @param str $dir              Directory to scan.
 * @param bol $count            Whether the return value should be the count result
 * 
 * @return bool|int Integer with count, TRUE or FALSE for check
 */
public function directory_with_contents($dir, $count = false) {

    try {
        if (!is_readable($dir)) return NULL;

        if ($count) {
            return count(scandir($dir));
        } else {
            return (count(scandir($dir)) == 2) ? false : true;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        throw new userman_Exception("<h1>ups!</h1><br/>". $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

The functions works well, but it is being used with directories that contain over one million files inside. The `scandir()` takes his time to return the results, and in turn this function with a large amount of files becomes slow.

Is any optimization that can be done as to have this function performing any faster when dealing with directories that have a large number of files?

Comment: As a side note, depending on the file system, a million files in a directory might be a bad idea.

Comment: @Corbin It's a Debian based server and the files are temporarily stored inside the directory while the process queue takes care of them!

Comment: Depending on the file system and what order your processing files in, you may be better of breaking the files into separate directories.  I can't remember for ext3 and ext4, but for ext2, a directory is essentially a linked list.  In other words, to open a file requires iterating over all of the file nodes ordered before it.  If you're not using ext2 though, I believe you should be fine.  Just thought it might be worth mentioning :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is there a catch for a PDOException?  Also, why are you masking it with another exception?  That doesn't make much sense.  How is the final catch block supposed to know what it's actually catching?

---

Anyway, you need to use a lower-level method than scandir.  You could use a [`DirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/directoryiterator) instance, but I would probably just go with [`opendir`](http://php.net/opendir).

For example:

```
 function is_directory_empty($path)
 {
      $dir = opendir($path);
      while (($f = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
           if ($f !== '.' && $f !== '..') {
                return true;
           }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

The important part here is that the loop bails upon finding the first file.  Additionally, `.` and `..` will usually be the first two entries, so it should only have to run 3 times at maximum (though that is implementation specific, I believe, since the dots are not required to be first -- if the dots aren't first, it would run at most twice for an empty directory and once for a non-empty one).

It's worth noting that this function has terrible error handling.  In particular, there's no way to know if the directory is empty or the `opendir` call failed.  You could throw an exception:

```
if ($dir === false) {
     //I chose UnexpectedValueException because it's what DirectoryIterator throws
     throw new UnexpectedValueException("Unable to open directory: {$path}");
}
```

Another way would be to take a more procedural, C-esque approach:

```
define('DIR_EMPTY', 0);
define('DIR_NOT_EMPTY', 1);
define('DIR_ERROR_OPEN', 2);

function is_directory_empty($path)
{
    $dir = opendir($path);
    if ($dir === false) {
         return DIR_ERROR_OPEN;
    }
    while (($f = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
         if ($f !== '.' && $f !== '..') {
              return DIR_EMPTY;
         }
    }
    return DIR_NOT_EMPTY;
}

$dir_empty = is_directory_empty("/some/path");
if ($dir_empty == DIR_EMPTY) {
    echo 'Empty!';
} else if ($dir_empty == DIR_NOT_EMPTY) {
    echo 'Not empty!';
} else {
    //(Should arguably be an else-if to check the last condition)
    echo 'Error opening path';
}
```

---

I would consider having your file-counting functionality, and your is-empty functionality be two separate functions.  There's a definite relation possible between them (is_empty(x) === !file_count(x)), but they're really different functionalities.

I'm not much a fan of a boolean flag changing the functionality of a function.  It's an anti-pattern in my opinion (and quite a few other people's opinion, though I'm too lazy to find links at the moment).

Instead, consider:

```
function count_directory_files($path)
{
    ...
}

function is_directory_empty($path)
{
    ...
}
```

The names clearly express the functionality.  There's no need for a magical flag.

`directory_with_contents` is a bit badly named to begin with, but if I had to guess what it does, I would guess that it returns true if a directory is empty, and false otherwise.  The counting-functionality is hidden.

(On the bad naming note: what does `directory_with_contents` mean?  Consider if you hadn't named it.  Could you look at that and know, with certainty, what it does?  I would imagine not.  In my opinion, functions that return booleans should typically be named as a binary predicate: `is_<object>_<property>`, `can_<object>_<property>`, etc.  [I'm actually a fan of camelCase, like, isDirectoryEmpty, but that's a superfluous opinion to this post :p.])

Comment: Thank you for the extensive analysis on the function. I'm also a fan of camelCase, but this function is to be supported by a underscore fan :D

Comment: Yes, the name is poor and so the methodology implemented I see, that's why I like coming here and read your reviews! ;)